# Windows 10 re-installation, can't skip product key screen?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have a valid copy of Windows 10 (upgraded from Windows 7 years ago), and recently I wanted change to its system language from Chinese to English and found my copy is locked to Chinese locale.

From googling, I can either:

- Reset my system via settings.
- or Download an english version of Windows 10 then re-install.

I picked the latter option as I wanted a clean install anyway.

So I downloaded an ISO from Microsoft's own site, which is English International + 64 bits + release 1803, and on the second screen I faced this screen:

[image: product key screen]

From googling it seems there should be a *"I don't have a product key"* option, but it was missing. And I certainly don't have a product key (the one used by my current system wasn't accepted by installer).

**So my question: is this route possible nowadays? Do I have to go with the reset route?**

---

Update, from the questions in comments:

- I believe my existing Windows 10 is a single language version, I have already set language/region preference to English/US but the interface remain Chinese.
- I already tried system reset, but after resetting, the setup interface starts with Chinese, and doesn't ask for my preferred language. I have set US as my region, however the interface remains Chinese.
- So I am attempting to replace it with a multi-language Windows 10. But the problem is I couldn't get pass the initial Product Key screen.
- I believe I have downloaded the right generic Windows 10 ISO, from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO, if it wasn't right, please point me to the right site.
- The ISO filename is `Win10_1803_EnglishInternational_x64.iso`

Update2:

- I tried some shady tool call [ShowKeyPlus](https://github.com/Superfly-Inc/ShowKeyPlus) and [a simple vbs script](https://www.howtogeek.com/206329/how-to-find-your-lost-windows-or-office-product-keys/) to uncover my installed and oem keys, but NONE of them are accpeted by the Windows 10 Installer.
- I discovered my machine originally has Windows 8 initially, not Windows 7. ShowKeyPlus tells me it's "Win 8 RTM CoreCountrySpecifc OEM:DM"
- My existing Windows 10 is "Windows 10 Home China"

**So basically, I need to get generic "windows 10 Home" onto it, but just couldn't find a way.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I tried some tool called ShowKeyPlus and a simple VBS script to uncover my installed and OEM keys, but NONE of them are accepted by the Windows 10 Installer.

ShowKeyPlus is providing your Windows 8 key.  Since you had a region-specific edition of Windows 8 it means you are only eligible for a region-specific edition of Windows 10.  In your case that would be Windows 10 Home China.

> So I am attempting to replace it with a multi-language Windows 10. But
> the problem is I couldn't get past the initial Product Key screen.

You will need to purchase a Windows 10 license key for Windows 10 Home.  You should also be able to upgrade, Windows 10 Home China, to Windows 10 Professional.

> I have a valid copy of Windows 10 (upgraded from Windows 7 years ago),
> and recently I wanted to change to its system language from Chinese to
> English and found my copy is locked to Chinese locale.

While Windows 7 Home only allowed you to install a single language pack, Windows 10 Home allows you to install multiple language packs, if your locale is locked to a specific locale it means didn't have Windows 10 Home installed but a regional specific product like Windows 10 Home Single Language or Windows 10 Home China.

Since you have already confirmed, you had a region-specific version of Windows 8 installed (not Windows 7), you were only eligible for the upgrade to Windows 10 Home China.  You should purchase Windows 10 Professional, Windows 10 Home, or upgrade Windows 10 Home China to Windows 10 Professional.

> I believe I have downloaded the right generic Windows 10 ISO, from
> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO, if it
> wasn't right, please point me to the right site.
>
> So I am attempting to replace it with a multi-language Windows 10. But the problem is I couldn't get past the initial Product Key screen.

You have the correct link, but you don't have a license for any edition contained on the ISO, you need to purchase one.

> I already tried a system reset, but after resetting, the setup
> interfaces start with Chinese and doesn't ask for my preferred
> language. I have set US as my region, however, the interface remains
> Chinese.

Windows 10 Home China is only sold in China, and the locale is locked, to a specific locale.